# SQL Developer, INSERT de fecha: error - ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy ejecutando esto para insertar valores en la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICIOS
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
    HORA TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    DISTANCIA DECIMAL (*,2) NULL,
    TIEMPO_REQUERIDO INTEGER NULL,
    DIRECCION_ORIGEN VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
    DIRECCION_DESTINO VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
    TARIFA DECIMAL (*,2) NULL,
    ESTADO VARCHAR2 (255) NULL,
    TARIFA_DINAMICA VARCHAR2(1) CHECK ((TARIFA_DINAMICA = 'V') OR (TARIFA_DINAMICA = 'F')),
    MEDIO_PAGO_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONDUCTOR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    VEHICULO_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CLIENTE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SERVICIO_COMPARTIDO_CLIENTE_ID INTEGER NULL
);

    insert into SERVICIOS (ID, FECHA, HORA, DISTANCIA, TIEMPO_REQUERIDO, DIRECCION_ORIGEN, DIRECCION_DESTINO, TARIFA, ESTADO, TARIFA_DINAMICA, MEDIO_PAGO_ID, CONDUCTOR_ID, VEHICULO_ID, CLIENTE_ID, SERVICIO_COMPARTIDO_CLIENTE_ID)

values (4923, '05/05/2018', '6:15 AM', 3.3, 33, '87445 Dorton Park', '589 Miller Parkway', 83502.13, 'INACTIVO', 33573.67, 15, 25, 29, 30, 90);
```

Pero me sale este error:

> Error que empieza en la línea: 2 del comando :
>   insert into SERVICIOS (ID, FECHA, HORA, DISTANCIA, TIEMPO_REQUERIDO, DIRECCION_ORIGEN, DIRECCION_DESTINO, TARIFA, ESTADO, TARIFA_DINAMICA, MEDIO_PAGO_ID, CONDUCTOR_ID, VEHICULO_ID, CLIENTE_ID, SERVICIO_COMPARTIDO_CLIENTE_ID)
>   
>    `values (4923, '05/22/2018', '6:15 AM', 3.3, 33, '87445 Dorton Park', '589 Miller Parkway', 83502.13, 'INACTIVO', 33573.67, 15, 25, 29, 30, 90)`
>   
>   Informe de error - ORA-01843: not a valid month

¿ En que estoy fallando ? He intentado varias cosas, y ninguna me ha funcionado.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, lo que sucede es que habia hecho un alter table antes, y al parecer la columna habia quedado en la ultima posicion y por eso me arrojaba este mensaje.

Gracias muchachos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, hay que leer lo que dicen los errores en tu caso tu error dice

"not a valid month"

y viendo como esta arrojando el error la fecha creo que me doy una idea tu formato de fecha deber ser dd/mm/yy que traducido seria -> dia/mes/año

entonces segun el error estas insertando una fecha no valida porque segun tu inserción 05/22/2018 , no existe un mes 22. Hay que checar bien los valores que estas insertando

Comment: Lo que sucede es que este insert lo hice primero por medio de un generador de datos, mockaroo, y yo escogi el formato mm/dd/yyyy  mes-dia-año entonces al poner '05/22/2018' seria Mayo-22-2018 y aun asi he intentado cambiar el formato y me falla con el mismo mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que tenia el mismo error, lo único que hice para solucionarlo fue cambiar el 16/05/2022 por 16/may/2022 y me funionó perfectamente.
Puedes intentarlo!.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).